# i have json data coming from an API and want to extract data from response using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

i have json data coming from an API in below format. and i want to extract selected data from it like its id, code, lat and lang only. anyone can help? i am using using core PHP.

```
$countries_data = json_decode($countries, true);
print_r($countries_data);

Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 241
                        [type] => country
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [code] => AF
                                [name] => Afghanistan
                                [lat] => 33.93911
                                [lng] => 67.709953
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 235
                        [type] => country
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [code] => AL
                                [name] => Albania
                                [lat] => 41.153332
                                [lng] => 20.168331
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 236
                        [type] => country
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [code] => DZ
                                [name] => Algeria
                                [lat] => 28.033886
                                [lng] => 1.659626
                            )

                    )
    )
    )
```

i tried below code but no success yet, it not giving the required output

```
$countries_data = $countries_data['data'];
$countries_att = array_column($countries_data, 'lat');
$countries_ids = array_column($countries_data, 'id');
$final = array_merge($countries_att, $countries_ids);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);

$res = array();
foreach($countries_att as $k => $v){
    $res[$k] = array_merge($countries_att[$k],$countries_ids[$k]);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

**i want only its id, code, lat and lng in below format**.

```
[0] => 
        [id] => 241
        [code] => AF
        [lat] => 33.93911
        [lng] => 67.709953
[1] => 
        [id] => 235
        [code] => AL
        [lat] => 41.153332
        [lng] => 20.168331
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that you could show us?

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: What have you tried to debug that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration the following JSON object:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"241",
         "type":"country",
         "attributes":{
            "code":"AF",
            "name":"Afghanistan",
            "lat":"33.93911",
            "lng":"67.709953"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"235",
         "type":"country",
         "attributes":{
            "code":"AL",
            "name":"Albania",
            "lat":"41.153332",
            "lng":"20.168331"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"236",
         "type":"country",
         "attributes":{
            "code":"DZ",
            "name":"Algeria",
            "lat":"28.033886",
            "lng":"1.659626"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The code to loop through the code and grab only the elements that you want could look something like this:

```
<?php

// Define our JSON locations object with our locations
$locations = '{"data":[{"id":"241","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan","lat":"33.93911","lng":"67.709953"}},{"id":"235","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"AL","name":"Albania","lat":"41.153332","lng":"20.168331"}},{"id":"236","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"DZ","name":"Algeria","lat":"28.033886","lng":"1.659626"}}]}';

// Decodes the JSON object and prints it out pretty-like
//print_r(json_decode($locations, true));

// Decode the JSON object to a PHP array
$locations = json_decode($locations, true);

// Loop through the newly created PHP array
$parsedLocations = [];

foreach ($locations['data'] AS $location)
{
  // Prints out the current location pretty-like
  //print_r($location);

  $id = $location['id'];
  $type = $location['type'];

  // This will be an array containing the items below
  $attributes = $location['attributes'];

  // $code = $attributes['code'];
  $code = $location['attributes']['code'];

  // $name = $attributes['name'];
  $name = $location['attributes']['name'];

  // $lat = $attributes['lat'];
  $lat = $location['attributes']['lat'];

  // $lng = $attributes['lng'];
  $lng = $location['attributes']['lng'];

  $parseLocations[] = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'type' => $type,
    'code' => $code,
    'name' => $name,
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lng' => $lng
  );
}

print_r($parseLocations);
```

The code above has been tested and works. I have shown you how to assign values to variables from the data in the parsed object and how to assign those variables into a new nested array. You could also do something like this:

```
<?php

// Define our JSON locations object with our locations
$locations = '{"data":[{"id":"241","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan","lat":"33.93911","lng":"67.709953"}},{"id":"235","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"AL","name":"Albania","lat":"41.153332","lng":"20.168331"}},{"id":"236","type":"country","attributes":{"code":"DZ","name":"Algeria","lat":"28.033886","lng":"1.659626"}}]}';

// Decodes the JSON object and prints it out pretty-like
//print_r(json_decode($locations, true));

// Decode the JSON object to a PHP array
$locations = json_decode($locations, true);

// Loop through the newly created PHP array
$parsedLocations = [];

foreach ($locations['data'] AS $location)
{
  // Prints out the current location pretty-like
  //print_r($location);

  $parsedLocations[] = array(
    'id' => $location['id'],
    'type' => $location['type'],
    'code' => $location['attributes']['code'],
    'name' => $location['attributes']['name'],
    'lat' => $location['attributes']['lat'],
    'lng' => $location['attributes']['lng']
  );
}

print_r($parsedLocations);
```

This should help get you where you need to be if I understood your question.

Comment: worked as perfect as i wanted, thank you very much for your help